# While True loop breaking early

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was expecting the result as:

```
1
2
3
rest of the code
```

However I only see:

```
1
rest of the code
```

Can anyone help clear my understanding?

This is my code:

```
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    print(i)
    if(i <= 3):
        break
print("rest of the code")
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) loop is

> for repeated execution as long as an expression is true

So instead of putting an `if` inside the loop, just use the loop's condition:

```py
i = 0
while i <= 3:
    i += 1
    print(i)

print("rest of the code")
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop stops, because `i` is equal to 1, so 1 < 3, so the `break` instruction is called.
Maybe the following code is what you want to achieve:

```
i=0
while True:
    i+=1
    print(i)
    if(i == 3):
        break
print("rest of the code")
```